# FCBKcomplete doesn't seem to work with CDN jquery

Tags: jquery, fcbkcomplete

I have jQuery included from Microsoft CDN using the following link:

https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js

I'm trying to use FCBKcomplete (http://www.emposha.com/javascript/jquerymultiselect.html). The problem is it doesn't work till I include the jquery.js file included in the download, and I have to remove the CDN jQuery link.

The problem is that the CDN jquery is included in the master file of my asp .net project.

I get the error:
Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'facebooklist' on the line:

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
      $.facebooklist('#facebook-demo', '', '#facebook-auto',{url:'fetched.php',cache:1}, 10, {userfilter:1,casesensetive:0});
    });
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

According to FCBKComplete's documentation here https://github.com/emposha/FCBKcomplete : "Jquery version required: 1.6.x"